# Do different mounts change your mounted cloak size?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

When cloaked (e.g. Nova or Zeratul) and not mounted, the blur you create is smaller than if you're mounted. Does the size of your mount impact the size of the cloak?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An *undocumented* change with [the March-24-2015 Patch](http://eu.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/18401781/heroes-closed-beta-patch-notes-march-24-2015-09-04-2015#Art): the mount doesn't create a blur anymore.

Source: [/r/heroesofthestorm](http://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/30rn1b/undocumented_change_you_can_no_longer_see_a_blur/)

[image]

[image]